# CNTK Trainer for multiple Outputs

Tags: c#, cntk

In the situation where CNTK has multiple Output Layers, should one Train with multiple Trainers?

```
List<Learner> learnersA = new List<Learner>() { Learner.SGDLearner(OutputLayerOne.Parameters(), learningRate) };
List<Learner> learnersB = new List<Learner>() { Learner.SGDLearner(OutputLayerTwo.Parameters(), learningRate) };

Trainer trainerA = Trainer.CreateTrainer(OutputLayerOne, loss, eval, learnersA);
Trainer trainerB = Trainer.CreateTrainer(OutputLayerTwo, loss, eval, learnersB);
```

Or is there a better way, training with a Trainer that Trains on multiple Functions?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have 2 loss functions. Currently in the world of optimisation, there only exist techniques to optimise a single loss function. For multi-task learning (i.e. more than one loss function), you will have to combine them to form a single loss.

Example:

```
loss1 = loss(output1, target1)
loss2 = loss(output2, target2)
final_loss = a * loss1 + (1-a) * loss2  # where `a` is the relative importance between the 2 loss.
```

You should also make sure that the 2 loss have the same unit, else it doesn't make sense to combine them together.

Comment: Excellent advice, Thank You! +1. My question is still unanswered, as the Trainers Initialised, because I have two Outputs, as functions, should I train each one separately with different 'Trainer's?

Comment: Your outputs are your losses. You have to combine them like i stated above. If the two outputs are completely independent of each other then you should train them separately, but since you are asking, i doubt this is the case.